# MongoDB replica set initialisation

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am trying to create a replica set with two replicas and one arbiter. All members are launched using:

`mongod --port 25670 --dbpath /data --replSet rs0`

The data directory is an empty directory.

On one of the replicas I run rs.initiate but I get the error

`replSetReconfig should only be run on PRIMARY, but my state is STARTUP2`

I have tried waiting for a PRIMARY to be elected but even after two minutes, I see no indication that an election has taken place.

How do I force the replica set to elect a PRIMARY? Or is there a way to predict the PRIMARY?

Comment: you need to connect to an instance, not to the repset. Please take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/ It's a step-by-step guide.

Comment: Not clear. I connect the client to the local instance and call rs.instantiate. I have read the guide and I believe I've followed it accurately.

Comment: Evidently something went wrong. If you update the question with exact steps you did it might help you to get a sensible answer. The message suggests the repset is configured and performs initial sync https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/#replstate.STARTUP2

Comment: Are all members in [`STARTUP2` state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/#replstate.STARTUP2)? This state suggests that the member you are trying to `rs.initiate()` on may already be in the process of initial sync. What specific version of MongoDB are you trying to install? What is the output of `rs.status()` on the member you are trying to initiate as a primary?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found to work consistently is as follows:

1. Shutdown all servers.
2. Launch the first replica server.
3. rs.initiate the replica set with only the first server.
4. Launch the second replica.
5. Add it to the replica set.
6. Finally launch and add the arbiter. For the arbiter it did not matter if I did addArb even before launching the arbiter instance.